# How to read multiple values in a column with a comma separator using python?

Tags: python

how to read multiple values in a column with a comma separator using python ? 
Column 1 has numerical values, Column 2 has alphabets with comma separator.

col1  col2
11    a, b, c
22    d, e, f
33    g, h, i

Comment: `My out put should be, a:[11, 44] , b: [ 11, 33]` - Can you explain?

Comment: col1 = userID,  col2 = [list of game id's separated by comma ]... when I want to check a particular game, my output should be  -> game : [list of user id's]

Comment: OK, please check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want new column of lists:

```
df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.split(',')
```

and if want new columns from column `col2`:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('col2').str.split(',', expand=True))
```

For dictionary need:

```
d1 = (df.set_index('col1')['col2']
       .str.split(',', expand=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name='a')
       .groupby('a')['col1']
       .apply(list)
       .to_dict())
print (d1)
{'a': [11], 'b': [11], 'c': [11], 'd': [22], 
 'e': [22], 'f': [22], 'g': [33], 'h': [33], 'i': [33]}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is make a data frame out of it using pandas.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=["Col1", "Col2"], header=0, index_col=False)
for i in range(len(df)):
    numerical = df['Col1'][i]
    alpha = df['Col2'][i].split(sep=',')
    print("Numerical: " + str(numerical))
    print("AlphaN: ")
    for j in range(len(alpha)):
        print(alpha[j] + " ")
```

Comment: My out put should be, a:[11, 44] , b: [ 11, 33]